# How to remove/clear previously drawn lines before redrawing new lines in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am drawing few lines using `paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)`. Sometime later if I want to draw new lines then the previously drawn lines are not cleared/removed. How could I draw the new lines only, by removing/clearing old lines. Is there any property to clear the previously drawn lines.Please let me know.

```
void QGraphWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    const QRect & rect = event->rect();
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    drawLines(painter, rect);//calling painter.drawLine() inside
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Show the code in paintEvent().

Comment: `void QGraphWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    const QRect & rect = event->rect();
 QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

 drawLines(painter, rect);//calling painter.drawLine() inside
}`

Comment: What is drawLines doing? Are you repainting only the requested region or the entire area? I see you're handling the rect() in the event.

Comment: How do you trigger a repaint when you update the lines ?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the correct approach is to clear the area before drawing new lines. This can be achieved either by using the autoFillBackground property as proposed by Stephen Chu, or by calling manually the [`QPainter::eraseRect()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html#eraseRect) before drawing your lines in the `QGraphWidget::paintEvent` method.

```
void QGraphWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    const QRect & rect = event->rect();
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.eraseRect(rect);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    drawLines(painter, rect);
}
```

Another option is to draw "negatively" the lines from the previous call to `QGraphWidget::paintEvent`. If you store the coordinate of your old lines, you might first draw lines using the background brush and then draw your new lines using the foreground brush. See code sample that might fit into you `drawLines` method. Note that if you draw something else in your widget, drawing the lines negatively might erase some of the other graphics which is why the first approach, erasing all the `GraphWidget` area, is better.

```
// save the current brush
QBrush currentBrush = painter.brush();
// draw the old line with the background brush
painter.setBrush(background());
painter.drawLine(oldLine);
// draw the new line with the current brush
painter.setBrush(currentBrush);
painter.drawLine(newLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to fill your widget with window background color before redraw. Set [autoFillBackground](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget) to true after you create the widget and Qt will handle this for you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a specific call to remove the line. If you're repainting the entire area each time `paintEvent()` function is called you shouldn't see previous lines. If you're not repainting the area, you'll have to draw over the line yourself. This code for instance is drawing a line in a different position each time the method is invoked:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
painter.drawRect(rect());
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::yellow));
static int i = 0;
painter.drawLine(QPointF(i, i), QPointF(i, height() - i));
i++;
```

but "previous lines" are cleared completely. If you want to keep those you'll have to repaint only a specific area or you'll have to repaint those.

Comment: Tried different options, but failed to update the graph with new lines. Previous lines are still there with new lines. Any other suggestions on this issue...

Comment: I don't have other suggestion if you don't show more of your code.

Answer (score -3):

This is one way to delete whole line from QT.

```
me->setFocus();
int pos;
QTextCursor tc= me->textCursor();
pos=tc.columnNumber();
tc.select(QTextCursor::LineUnderCursor);
QString str=tc.selectedText();
tc.removeSelectedText();

tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
tc.insertText(str);
tc.insertBlock();
tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousBlock,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfLine,QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
me->setTextCursor(tc);
return true;
```

Comment: I am not talking about delete text lines. I am talking about lines drawn like (x1,y1,x2,y2) on my Widget. This I am doing using QPaintEvent.